# How to extract data from URLs using preg_match()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, amazon-product-api

I need to extract ASIN numbers (10-character alphanumeric SKU) from Amazon URLs. The URLs are always in these formats:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/[text]/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/[text]/dp/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/[text]/dp/[text]/ASIN
```

There are usually more directories, as well as variables, after the ASIN number in the URL. Here is a full URL as an example:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Google-Nexus-Tablet-7-Inch-Black/dp/B00DVFLJDS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1387937682&sr=8-1&keywords=nexus+7
```

I think this might be possible to do using `preg_match()`, but I'm *very* new to regex and don't have a clue to formulate the expression.

Is this possible to do with `preg_match()`? If not, what would be the best approach to solving this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I've been reading up on regex and was able to modify the answer to work when the ASIN isn't at the very end of the URL string (which it rarely is):

```
#\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})#
```

I also made it so that there has to be a forward slash before the match.

Comment: It is possible to do with `preg_match()`. Now take some article and just learn how to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is possible and shouldn't be that difficult as you are searching for only one distinct group. But you still have to research this yourself - when you struggle with a concrete attempt, feel free to ask again

Comment: As @zerkms pointed out this is possible.  It is expected that you at least make an attempt before seeking help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying to figure it out and will update my question once I have a semi-reasonable attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('#([A-Za-z0-9]{10})$#', $url, $matches);
```

In short: `[A-Za-z0-9]` takes any alphanumeric character, ucase and lcase both allowed, `{10}` requires it exactly 10 times, and `$` requires it to be at the end of the string. The parentheses `(` and `)` define which part(s) you want to get back in the 3rd `$matches` output variable. Finally it's all surrounded by 2 `#`'s as regex delimiters.

Now go [read every article in the left sidebar of this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) so you can do it yourself next time :)

Comment: Kudos for explaining what your solution does rather than just saying, 'do this'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Niels's answer:

```
preg_match('#.*/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})/?$#', $url, $matches);
```

In case `[text]` is an alphanumeric with 10 characters.