# How write a regex that matches only when there's a slash OR nothing after the match?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_match()` to extract 10-character ASIN numbers from Amazon URLs. The URLs could be in any of these basic formats:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/[text]/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/[text]/dp/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/[text]/dp/[text]/ASIN
```

NOTE: The problem I'm having stems from the fact that there may or may not be slashes and variables at the end of the URLs, after the ASIN.

With the help I received in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984564/how-to-extract-data-from-urls-using-preg-match), I came up with this:

```
\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})
```

Which I thought was working, until I tried it on this URL:

```
http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-2-Console-Slim-Black/dp/B000TLU67W/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1389314719&sr=8-4&keywords=playstation+1
```

The output of `preg_match()` for that is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /PlayStatio
    [1] => PlayStatio
)
```

So then I tried adding a slash at the end of the regex, like this:

```
\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/
```

Which fixes the problem, giving the following output for the above URL:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /B000TLU67W/
    [1] => B000TLU67W
)
```

However, there won't always be a slash at the end of the URL. For example, the above URL works just fine on Amazon if modified to this:

```
http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-2-Console-Slim-Black/dp/B000TLU67W
```

My modified regex doesn't work for this URL, because there's no slash on the end.

I think maybe having an OR condition to see if there's either a slash after the match, or nothing after it, might work, but I'm not sure how to do it..

Is there any way to get the regex to work with both of the above URLs?

Comment: I would recommend that you change the title of this question to be more specific, i.e. something like: _"Regex to get ASIN value from Amazon URL"_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
'#/([A-Z0-9]{10})(?=$|[/?#])#i'
```

i.e. 10 digit alphanumerics followed by a slash OR `?` OR just end of input.

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aE0jU8

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it.  This is definitely the correct answer though.

Comment: Can be shortened with the `i` modifier though and `\d`: `#/([A-Z\d]{10})(?:/|\?|$)#i`

Comment: Notice there will always have the issue for products with a 10-letter name, like `http://www.amazon.com/FooProduct/dp/L33T42G33K/ref=sr_8_2` (fake url, obv.). I would suggest to use `[A-Z0-9]{10}` with a **case sensitive** regex to reduce chances to have this issue.

Comment: Sure `i` flag can be removed from above to match only capital letters and numbers BUT it will still match `/ANYPRODUCT/` on a URL for eg.

Comment: I provide an alternative in my answer, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Note that the path portion of a URL may end with an EOL/EOS, a `?` (query) or `#` (fragment). Thus, the `(?:/|\?|$)` portion of your regex would be better written as: `(?=$|[/?#])`

Comment: Oh yes that is correct @ridgerunner: Thanks so much for sound advise.

Comment: You're welcome. Take a look at my newly posted answer for an alternative solution for the other problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just find the *last* possible ASIN value in the URL path, like so:

```php
if (preg_match('%
    # Fetch ASIN value from Amazon URL.
    (?<=/)                  # ASIN value always preceeded by slash.
    [A-Za-z0-9]{10}         # The ASIN value is exactly 10 alphanum.
    (?=                     # Assert no more ASIN values in path.
      (?:                   # Zero or more non-ASIN path segments.
        /                   # Path segment always begins with slash.
        (?!                 # Assert this path segment not ASIN.
          [A-Za-z0-9]{10}   # Is valid ASIN value if followed by
          (?:$|[/?\#])      # EOL/EOS or / or ? or # terminator.
        )                   # End assert this path segment not ASIN.
        (?:                 # Zero or more URI path characters.
          [A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:@]  # Either URI path char,
        | \%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}  # or URI encoded value.
        )*                  # Zero or more URI path characters.
      )*                    # Zero or more non-ASIN path segments.
      (?=$|[?\#])           # Path ends on EOS, query or fragment.
    )                       # End assert no more ASIN values in path.
    %x', $subject, $matches)) {
    $ASIN = $matches[0];
} else {
    $ASIN = "";
}
```

**Edited 20140110 12:30MDT**: First version did not correctly handle a lone slash at end of path.

Answer (score 1):

> **tl;dr :** `(?:o|dp(?:\/[^/]+)?|gp\/product(?:\/[^/]+)?)\/([A-Z0-9]{10})`

I would like to enligth a problem you'll have, with 10-letters named products.

Let's take a **`CoffeeCups`** product, with a ASIN equal to **`C0FF33CUP5`**, and the related urls :

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/C0FF33CUP5
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/CoffeeCups/C0FF33CUP5  [*]
http://www.amazon.com/o/C0FF33CUP5
http://www.amazon.com/dp/C0FF33CUP5
http://www.amazon.com/CoffeeCups/dp/C0FF33CUP5
http://www.amazon.com/CoffeeCups/dp/some-text/C0FF33CUP5
```

### Our issue

Original regex `\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/` will fail for starred `[*]` url :

```
// http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/CoffeeCups/C0FF33CUP5
Array
(
    [0] => /CoffeeCups/
    [1] => CoffeeCups
)
```

Whatever there are a trailing slash, or other parameters after, this regex is already useless. You need to use a better one.

### Case sensitive way

I first suggested to use case sensitive regex : `\/([A-Z0-9]{10})\/`, so we've got :

```
// http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/CoffeeCups/C0FF33CUP5
Array
(
    [0] => /C0FF33CUP5/
    [1] => C0FF33CUP5
)
```

But are we sure ASIN will always be capitalized ?

### A better way

A better way would be to take in account every pattern possible, to be sure we're getting the ASIN (capitalized or not), and not the product name.

Here's one you can try :

```
(?:o|dp(?:\/[^/]+)?|gp\/product(?:\/[^/]+)?)\/([A-Z0-9]{10})
```

[image]

```
(?:
    o                        # o
  | dp(?:\/[^/]+)?           # dp, dp/some-text
  | gp\/product(?:\/[^/]+)?  # gp/product, gp/product/some-text
)
\/                           # /
([A-Z0-9]{10})               # ASIN
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nN0rB9)